# Yammer Export Data

Tags: yammer

I am hoping you can help me with a problem regarding Yammer Export Data.
I have followed the steps in https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2. received a token code and copied the example 
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export?since=2012-02-09T00:00:00+00:00&access_token=WOI87382HDL replacing the access_token with my token. But I get the error "This sight can't be reached". I know I am doing something stupid but don't know what. Any help would be much appreciated.
Cheers 
Paul

Answer (score 0):

https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export?since=2016-04-09T00:00:00&model=Message&include=csv with a bearer token for a verified admin works for me. Note that I only added the params of &model=Message&include=csv to ensure I didn't grab all the files in my network which could take awhile depending on the size of your data.

Is the user you are using a verified admin of the network?